# NURB curve represented as 2D array

Tags: c++, opengl, graphics, 2d, nurbs

I'm writing a c++ program which needs to store all of the NURB curve points in 2D array.

To picture it i will use simple example with straight line:

```
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
[1][1][1][1]
[ ][ ][ ][ ]
```

Where 1's represent coordinates of this curve.

At first I've been thinking of drawing nurb curve in openGL and then read the pixels and store them in 2D array.
But this seems to be very inefficient.

Do you know of any better way of generating such curve in 2d array given required parameters?

Comment: If you already have NURB curve definition, you can evaluate as many points on the curve as you want. Why do you need to store these points?

Comment: I need to store it array in order to perform many computation on nurb, anyway I've managed to do it with CoxDeBoor algorithm. I think the other way is to set glu callback function to get each vertex(not sure about this solution), anyway thanks for interest, problem is solved :)